# Ruby | form_with url: @variable not routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, erb

In my Ruby erb view ->

Why would this form_with route as expected on submit:

```
<%= form_with url: new_cmd_gllic_controller_path, method: 'get' do |f| %>
```

But this string built one does not?
Goes to {parent resource}/new_cmd_gllic_path instead

```
<% @var= 'cmd_gllic %>
<% @filePath = 'new_' + @var+ '_controller_path'%>

<%= form_with url: @filePath, method: 'get' do |f| %>
```

routes.rb:

```
  get 'new_cmd_gllic_controller', to: 'cmd_gllic#new', as: :new_cmd_gllic_controller
```

Comment: look at the html form tag produced by the two approaches... the working approach vs. the non-working approach. Are they the same?

Comment: its probably missing the '/' ? as in '/new_cmd_gllic_controller_path' vs 'new_cmd_gllic_controller_path'

Comment: both of you are correct. Can't believe I didn't think to check the rendered html. Rails... convention over configuration.... Thank you!!!